# method getLong(int) is undefined for SherlockFragmentList

Tags: android

i want to show a contact list on a SherlockFragmentList on tab in actionbar. i follow the [android develop tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)  but i get following error when i try to get the id values inside the onItemClick method :
(The method getLong(int) is undefined for the type ContactListFragment)

```
 public class ContactListFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { 
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long rowID) {
    //Get The Cursor
    Cursor cursor = ((SimpleCursorAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).getCursor();
    //move to the selected contact
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    //get the id value
    mContactId = getLong(CONTACT_ID_INDEX);
    mContactKey = getString(LOOKUP_KEY_INDEX);
    mContactUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(mContactId, mcontactKey);

}
```

Any help here?
Thanks

Comment: add `cursor.getLong` .It'll help

Answer (score 6):

I think a `cursor` is missing, see also the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html):

```
Cursor cursor = ((SimpleCursorAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).getCursor();
//move to the selected contact
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
//get the id value
mContactId = cursor.getLong(CONTACT_ID_INDEX);
mContactKey = cursor.getString(LOOKUP_KEY_INDEX);
```

EDIT: Filled bug [59330](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59330) for this issue